# Delphi XE Open database on network share (unsupported on-disk structure error)

Tags: database, delphi, networking

I am trying to open a database with my Delphi XE application using the BDE.
When I open the database on a local drive, all is well.
When I copy said database to a network share and attempt to open it, I get the error message 'General SQL error. Unsupported on-disk structure for file ; found 11.1, support 11.0'
Does anyone have an idea what is wrong, and how to fix it?

I have a firebird v. 2.1.5.18497 installed and running as the FirebirdServerDefaultInstance service (I assume that is the program behind the service)

Comment: I remember that I was getting this error message from a management tool (FlameRobin I think) when I was trying to attach a database when the Firebird server could not start (due to occupied default port). It's been quite difficult to manage what's going on. Today I would suggest just switching to a different DBMS, but if it's too late or you cannot use a different DBMS, you may start by checking [`this blog post`](http://wiert.me/2009/09/03/firebirdinterbase-unsupported-on-disk-structure-for-file-found-32779-13-support/).

Comment: Not sure if this might help [Unsupported on-disk structure for file mydatabase.fdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957235/unsupported-on-disk-structure-for-file-mydatabase-fdb)

Comment: `When I copy said database to a network share` -> trouble 100% guaranteed

Comment: How are you connecting to the database (both locally and on the shared drive)? It sounds like you have two versions of Firebird installed (a 2.0 embedded and the 2.1.5 client/server version). I wouldn't mind betting you are using localhost: in your connection string on your local machine (which will use the client/server version) and a mapped drive letter for the shared drive which will use the embedded version hence the error.

Comment: As a bonus info, I have been trying to open the databases using Flamerobin. Here I get 
'Unsuccessful execution caused by an unavailable resource', 'Engine Message: unavailable database' 
when trying to connect to the remote location database, local databases have no issues.

Comment: @Andy_D, that is really helpful and I'll make sure to check this (how do you conclude I have a 2.0 version installed?)

Comment: Firebird On Disk Structure 11.0 pertains to Firebird 2.0 and 11.1 is Firebird 2.1. I suspect the database was created in 2.1 and is trying to be accessed by version 2.0, hence the 'Found 11.1, support 11.0 message'. If you post the connection strings for both local and networked databases, this should confirm my hypothesis.

Comment: remote host connection strings:
path: Bubi:\!people!\bjarke.moeholt\wstest8\SCI\3z1\3z1.gdb
UNCPath: \\Bubi\people\bjarke.moeholt\wstest8\SCI\3z1\3z1.gdb



Local host connection strings:
path: 127.0.0.1:E:\Shares\bjarke.moeholt\workspaces\wstest8\SCI\3z1\3z1.gdb
UNCPath: E:\Shares\bjarke.moeholt\workspaces\wstest8\SCI\3z1\3z1.gdb

Comment: Looks to me like you're spot on Andy_D